# Auto detection of TLS ( self signed) scrape endpoint by Prometheus on k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, minio

I am scraping metrics of a service on a Kubernetes cluster. I just annotated the service so that Prometheus detects and start scraping 
automatically. 
 
The following annotations were added to the service:

```
metadata:
 annotations:
 prometheus.io/path: /minio/prometheus/metrics
 prometheus.io/port: "9000"
 prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

This works fine as long as the service is not configured with TLS. However when I enable TLS (HTTPS) Prometheus is no longer able to discover and scrape the service automatically.  To scrape from TLS enabled server I need to explicitly add the scrape endpoint with `insecure_skip_verify`. I am using self signed certificate.

Is there any way I can configure Prometheus in such way that it can discover and start scraping endpoints automatically when endpoints are TLS enabled with self signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is for your app to expose a non-TLS metrics deicated port so you can have all traffic secured and metrics exposed with clear http. That is the way that's suggested for ie. Istio for mTLS and healthchecks

```
You can use a separate port for health check and enable mutual TLS only
on the regular service port.
```

other then that you can add tls config to your scrape targets  so if you have your own selfsigned CA add it's cert here and it should be fine.